# How to use member variables in switch statements?

Tags: c++, switch-statement

When i tried using a member varible as *case* inside a switch statement the program wouldn't compile

```
class Foo{
public:
    // outside the function
    const int val = 1;

    void bar(){
        switch (1){
            case val:
                // ...
                break;
            default:
                // ...
                break;
        }   

    }   
};
```

gcc gives me this error:

> use of ‘this’ in a constant expression

but when I declare the variable as a local variable it compiles just fine

```
class Foo{
    public:
    void bar(){
        // inside the function
        const int val = 1;
        switch (1){
            case val:
                // ...
                break;
            default:
                // ...
                break;
        }   

    }   
};
```

Why does this happen and how can I use member variables in switch statements?

Comment: Change `const` to `constexpr`. Or use *enumerations*.

Comment: The problem with the non-static `const` member is that a `foo` constructor could give `val` a different value for each instance of the class.

Comment: That way the switch is resolved at compile time https://godbolt.org/g/cwQ6wp . Usually it doesn't happen https://godbolt.org/g/2EyKnQ

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C++ switches are compile time constructs, there isn't much reason for it, it just is. As such, all case labels must be constant expressions, aka compile time constants.

Within your example, `val` is just immutable, not a constant expression, hence the error. To fix it, you may either use `static const` or `static constexpr`

```
class Foo
{
    static const int val = 1;      // this
    static constexpr int val = 1;  // or this
};
```

Comment: "there isn't much reason for it": implementing a switch with compile-time constants and with variables are two very different things. It was wise from the point of view of the C designers (yes, C) to abstain from supporting such "dynamic" switches. By the way, how would you handle two equal case values ?

Comment: `how would you handle two equal case values ?` Both cases would be entered (unless the execution has broken out of the switch).

Comment: @YvesDaoust I can only say it simplifies the compiler, but not by a meaningful amount. Switches obviously are logically equivalent to multiple ifs. If arbitrary variables can be used, a decent optimizer will still optimize out the case where all of them are constant expressions. Equal values may be handled in a predefined order, such as top to bottom. See Go's switches, which is vastly more useful because of this.

Comment: @YvesDaoust [Switches should have always been syntactic sugar](https://godbolt.org/g/TpjddW), but syntactic sugar is still important.

Comment: The compiler can optimize compile-time switch statements better than if-statements or even dynamic switches. One example is an array containing jump pointers, where the switch value plus some constant is used as the index.

Comment: @MarkJeronimus Did you read the assembly in the link above and see they are identical?

Answer (score 2):

Declare it as a `static const`. It shouldn't really be a variable (either constant or not), it should be a compile-time constant.